# Reload current fragment on locale changed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, locale

I have language changer which is in activity. In my current situation I use `recreate()`, but this way it redraw first fragment. Example: I had four pages which are fragments. When I am at let say fourth and I change language - it redraw the first one. Is there a way to change activity local and to say on current fragment(translated of course)?

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            int check = 0;
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                check = check + 1;
                if(check>1) {
                    switch ((int)id) {
                        case 0:
                            locale = new Locale("fr");
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            locale = new Locale("en");
                            breakk          
                    }
                    Locale.setDefault(locale);
                    Configuration config = new Configuration();
                    config.locale = locale;
                    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                         getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                    recreate();
                }
            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: so you want to refresh the content only on the current fragment?

Comment: Is it really necessary to reload the entire `Fragment`? Can't you just update one of its views? And is your `Fragment` in a `ViewPager`?

Comment: Nope, it is not i ViewPager. I am not sure that I have to reload it. What are you suggest?

Comment: You can access your `Fragment`'s root view with the `getView()` method. Or, if you want to update something specific (i.e. a `TextView` with newly translated text) you can retrieve it via a getter in your fragment (`fragment.getTextView().setText()`)

Comment: This answer did not lead to anywhere

Comment: @TeodorKolev have you find any solution? same problem here